# How to submit multiple forms on one page with one button or pressing enter

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have been trying to find a way or examples on how to submit multiple forms on one php page with one submit button or with pressing enter on the keyboard but had no success.

Tried AJAX but failed to make it work. I tried other posted answers to similar questions it still doesn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript">
submitMultipleForms= function(){
//Submit first form
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
//...
document.getElementById("form2").submit();
}
</script>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank" name="form1">
<input name="accuracy" type="text" />
<input name="accuracyID" type="hidden" value="1234" />
 <input name="studentAccuracy" type="hidden" value="3456" />
 <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank" name="form2">
<input name="independent" type="text" />
<input name="independentID" type="hidden" value="1234" />
<input name="studentindependent" type="hidden" value="3456" />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form2" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitMultipleForms()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although it hasn't worked, it would be nice to see the work you have done so far. Maybe we can improve that!

Comment: You can only submit 1 form per request and `.submit` triggers a request. If you want to submit multiple forms at once either merge them or send multiple AJAX requests from the same page.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with javascript without Jquery

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitMultipleForms()" />
```

If you can access your form with an **id** :

```
submitMultipleForms= function(){
    //Submit first form
    document.getElementById("form_1").submit();
    //...
    document.getElementById("form_2").submit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much please see the code in my original post

Comment: add id="" attribute as well, ID is not equal to name,so do something like : <form id="form_1" action.... and <form id="form_2" action....

Comment: Thanks but it only submits the first form!

Comment: <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank" name="form1" id="form1">
<input name="accuracy" type="text" />
<input name="accuracyID" type="hidden" value="111234" />
<input name="studentAccuracy" type="hidden" value="134222" />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>

Comment: Edit your question and show me your current code,